# solving a system of 2 non-linear equations with 2 unknowns

Tags: problem-solving, nonlinear-system

i'm trying to find a solution for these two equations, $p$ & $q$ are variables and $c$ is known constant (it's given randomly) :

$$
\begin{align}
F_1=&\left(p^2q^2(p^2-q^2)+c^2(p^4+q^4-6p^2q^2)-3c^4(p^2-q^2)-4c^6\right)\sin(p)\sinh(q)+\\&2pq\left(-p^2q^2+3c^2(p^2-q^2)-7c^4\right)\cos(p)\cosh(q)-\\&pq\left(p^4+q^4+2c^2(q^2-p^2)+2c^4\right)\cos(2c)
\\
F_2=&2cp\left(3p^2q^2-q^4-c^2(p^2+q^2)+4c^4\right)\cos(p)\sinh(q)+\\&2cq\left(p^4-3p^2q^2-c^2(p^2+q^2)-4c^4\right)\sin(p)\cosh(q)+\\&pq(p^2+q^2)(q^2-p^2+2c^2)\sin(2c)
\end{align}
$$

($F_1$ is taken from real part of an equation and $F_2$ is taken from its imaginary part and both are equal to zero)

i want to solve $F_1$ & $F_2$ to find $p$ and $q$ for a given $c$
i tried with both maple and matlab with solve command but it takes a long time running for them and finally there's no answer & my PC gets slow !

$p$ and $q$ are real variables (they were taken from a complex unknown previously $p+qi$, i mean we know that $p$ and $q$ must be Real)

any procedure or solution that can help or maybe a way to solve with maple or matlab is appreciated .
thanks a lot in advance.